# Blob is not working right in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I write the code in react to send the JSON data with file to Backend Server and it looks fine but when i send the same data in React Native there is exception of multipart form data.

Here is the code i tried on React Side and it works properly:

```
  const incident = {
    'incidentDateTime': '05-Apr-2019 12:39',
    'description': 'desc',
    'actionTaken': 'Action Taken',
    'additionalInformation': '',
    'incidentTypeId': 1,
    'communityId': 1,
    'reporterId': 2,
    'reporterName': 'test user'
  }

  formData.append('incident', new Blob([JSON.stringify(incident)], {
      type: 'application/json'
    })
  )


  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://18.XXX.XX.XXX:80XX/api/',
    headers: { 'x-authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXX' }
  })

  instance.post('incidents', formData)
```

It works fine but if i send data in this same pattern in React Native.Server will give exception that no multipart form data.
I am tried with react-native-fetch-blob package. Follow is the code through react-native-fetch-blob

```
  import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'


  const BlobRN = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob
  const formData = new FormData()

    const incident = {
      // 'id': 0,
      'incidentDateTime': '05-Apr-2019 12:39',
      'description': 'desc',
      'actionTaken': 'Action Taken',
      'additionalInformation': '',
      'incidentTypeId': 1,
      'communityId': 1,
      'reporterId': 2,
      'reporterName': 'test user'
    }


    const blobAttrs = { type: 'application/json' }
    const blobPromise = BlobRN.build(incident, blobAttrs)

    blobPromise.then(blobInstance => {

      formData.append('incident', {
        uri: fileInstance._ref,
        type: fileInstance.type,
        name: fileInstance.name
      })

      const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://18.XXX.XX.XX:80XX/api/',
        headers: { 'x-authorization': 'Bearer XXXX' }
      })

      instance.post('incidents', formData)
    })
```

[Here is the snapshot of request when tried through react-native-fetch-blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S45Ga.png)

Comment: They have an example [right here](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob#multipartform-data-example-post-form-data-with-file-and-data). Have you tried using `RNFetchBlob.fetch()` instead of axios? Axios might not know what to do with a polyfill for a blob.

Comment: Well that's not a native Blob. Not surprised that FormData doesn't know how to handle it, quite surprised it doesn't come as "[object Object]" though. But, why are you sending your JSON data as a File? You won't win much than if you sent it as part of the form-data (`formData.append('incident', JSON.stringify(incident))`)